# Cannot configure AWS CloudWatch logs for ECS containers in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I cannot configure AWS CloudWatch logs for ECS containers in terraform. I'm getting:

```
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://logs.ue-west-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup logs.ue-west-1.am
```

My container definition:

```
  [{
    "essential": false,
    "memory": 500,
    "name": "client",
    "cpu": 500,
    "image": "some_image",
    "portMappings": [
        {
            "containerPort": 3000,
            "hostPort": 3000
        }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "example-production-client",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "example-production-client",
        "awslogs-region": "ue-west-1"
      }
    }
  }]
```

And my terraform definitions looks like:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "example-production-client" {
  name = "example-production-client"

  tags = {
    Environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "example-production-client" {
  name           = "example-production-client"
  log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example-production-client.name
}
```

What am I missing here? Have you experienced the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have typed an incorrect region, change the region to either "us-west-1" or "eu-west-1" -

```
    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1"
```